# How to maintain similar variable name in component & in state - VUEJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm going to use a similar variable in state and in a component as well like below,

> store.js

```
{
  export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      title: 'Component Block'
    }
  })
}
```

> ComponentA.vue

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
     title: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
   ...mapState(['title'])
  }
}
```

Is there any way to differentiate either state variable or component variable without changing the variable names causing of similar name?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a shared name across data/methods/computed properties at the moment in Vue.

If you are wedded to using a data property call `title`, you can key your `mapState`:

```
...mapState({
    titleFromStore: 'title'
})
```

But it's worth considering why we can't use the same name. It would add a layer of confusion to your code. When referring to `this.title`, which one would you be referring to? This limit is there for a good reason, I'd recommend renaming the data property.